# How to test a confirm dialog with Cucumber?

Tags: automated-tests, capybara, integration-testing

I am using Ruby on Rails with Cucumber and Capybara.

How would I go about testing a simple confirm command ("Are you sure?")?

Also, where could I find further documentation on this issue?

Comment: If you are using Capybara-webkit, you will find your answer there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930927/how-do-i-confirm-a-javascript-popup-with-capybara#

Comment: Any one pls help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77977493/facing-issue-in-pactum-cucumber-undefined-error

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Seems like there's no way to do it in Capybara, unfortunately. But if you're running your tests with the Selenium driver (and probably other drivers that support JavaScript), you can hack it. Just before performing the action that would bring up the confirm dialog, override the `confirm` method to always return true. That way the dialog will never be displayed, and your tests can continue as if the user had pressed the OK button. If you want to simulate the reverse, simply change it to return false.

```
page.evaluate_script('window.confirm = function() { return true; }')
page.click('Remove')
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore in Firefox 4... @derek-ekins solution below, from what Google tells me, seems to be more forward-compatible, though I can't confirm just yet (I'm stuck on Capybara 0.3.9).

Comment: See answer below for using "page.driver.browser.switch_to ..."

Answer (score 136):

The selenium driver [now supports this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings#JavaScript_dialogs)

From Capybara you would access it like this:

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
```

or

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.dismiss
```

or

```
 page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.text
```

Comment: For anyone else following this - please note that Derek's answer does indeed work where I found that the code in the official Selenium documentation did not (cucumber / Selenium). Note the presence of `page.driver.browser` in Derek's answer

Comment: Peter - the code here is tailored specifically for using capybara whereas the code in the docs are for when you are using selenium-webdriver directly - I wrote that example as well so I hope it works!

Comment: Ahh. Yes, good point and completely missed by me. In that case thank you for both examples.

Answer (score 39):

I've implemented these two web steps in `/features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb`:

```
When /^I confirm popup$/ do
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept    
end

When /^I dismiss popup$/ do
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.dismiss
end
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to specifically test the message being displayed, here's a particularly hacky way to do so. I don't endorse it as beautiful code, but it gets the job done. You'll need to load http://plugins.jquery.com/node/1386/release, or change it to do cookies natively if you don't want jQuery.

Use this sort of story:

```
Given I am on the menu page for the current booking
And a confirmation box saying "The menu is £3.50 over budget. Click Ok to confirm anyway, or Cancel if you want to make changes." should pop up
And I want to click "Ok"
When I press "Confirm menu"
Then the confirmation box should have been displayed
```

And these steps

```
Given /^a confirmation box saying "([^"]*)" should pop up$/ do |message|
  @expected_message = message
end

Given /^I want to click "([^"]*)"$/ do |option|
  retval = (option == "Ok") ? "true" : "false"

  page.evaluate_script("window.confirm = function (msg) {
    $.cookie('confirm_message', msg)
    return #{retval}
  }")
end

Then /^the confirmation box should have been displayed$/ do
  page.evaluate_script("$.cookie('confirm_message')").should_not be_nil
  page.evaluate_script("$.cookie('confirm_message')").should eq(@expected_message)
  page.evaluate_script("$.cookie('confirm_message', null)")
end
```

Comment: Cool solution! I flipped it around a little which feels more natural to me: https://gist.github.com/727614

Comment: And here's another version of that code which supports both alert and confirm boxes, https://gist.github.com/919116

Answer (score 3):

Updating this for current releases of Capybara.  Most Capybara drivers today support the modal API.  To accept a confirm modal you would do

```
accept_confirm do  # dismiss_confirm if not accepting
  click_link 'delete'  # whatever action triggers the modal to appear
end
```

This can be used in Cucumber with something like

```
When /^(?:|I )press "([^"]*)" and confirm "([^"]*)"$/ do |button, msg|
  accept_confirm msg do
    click_button(button)
  end
end
```

which will click the named button and then accept a confirm box with text matching msg

Answer (score 2):

The [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) driver supports this as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
Scenario: Illustrate an example has dialog confirm with text
    #     
    When I confirm the browser dialog with tile "Are you sure?"
    #
=====================================================================
my step definition here:

And(/^I confirm the browser dialog with title "([^"]*)"$/) do |title|
  if page.driver.class == Capybara::Selenium::Driver
    page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.text.should eq(title)
    page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
  elsif page.driver.class == Capybara::Webkit::Driver
    sleep 1 # prevent test from failing by waiting for popup
    page.driver.browser.confirm_messages.should eq(title)
    page.driver.browser.accept_js_confirms
  else
   raise "Unsupported driver"
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[Prickle](https://github.com/ExtractMethod/prickle#popup) adds some handy convenience methods for working with popups in selenium and webkit

Answer (score 0):

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/1245226) has steps to test a JS confirm dialog in Rails 2 and 3 with any Capybara driver.

It's an adaptation of a previous answer, but doesn't need the jQuery Cookie plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the above answers with no luck. In the end this worked for me:

```
@browser.alert.ok
```