# cucumber file download confirm

Tags: file, download, cucumber, confirmation

I have a cucumber step where the file gets downloaded, but i am unable to click the save button in the dialog box that a browser provides, with cucumber step.

I have found some pages which solves the similar kind of problems, but it didn't solve mine

[How to test a confirm dialog with Cucumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458632/how-to-test-a-confirm-dialog-with-cucumber/2609244#2609244)

I have included this cucumber step for file download

```
When /^I confirm a js popup on the next step$/ do
  page.evaluate_script("window.alert = function(msg) { return true; }")
  page.evaluate_script("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }")
end
```

But didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try the page.driver syntax?

i.e., from: [How to test a confirm dialog with Cuccumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458632/how-to-test-a-confirm-dialog-with-cucumber/2609244#2609244):

```
When /^I confirm popup$/ do
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept    
end

When /^I dismiss popup$/ do
 page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.dismiss
end
```

ian.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but since this was one of the first SO posts I came across when searching for solutions, I figured I'd post a solution.

We can use good ol Ruby, along with open-uri (so include open-uri in your Gemfile if you aren't already using it):

```
Then /^I receive a PDF$/ do
  link_url = find_link("Report")[:href]
  file = open(link_url)
  file.content_type.should == 'application/pdf'
end
```