# Capybara switch_to.alert (dialog box) intermittent failure

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to interact with a dialog box in FF using RSPEC / Capybara.

Found a elegant solution in: [How to test a confirm dialog with Cucumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458632/how-to-test-a-confirm-dialog-with-cucumber)

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
```

However we're getting intermittent failures when the switch doesn't happen.

Anyone encountered this? Anyway to ensure the switch is always successful?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the answer states, the Browser becomes unresponsive when the modal Alert/Confirm/Prompt dialog boxes open. Nowadays, even though browsers have learnt to show non-modal windows, Capybara still can't evaluate any code in the page context.

As the linked answer states, just stub the `window.confirm` method. That is the best stable way.

You can write the following two steps in Capybara:

```
When /I ensure the confirm box returns OK/ do
  page.evaluate_script('window.confirm = function() { return true; }')
end

When /I ensure the confirm box returns Cancel/ do
  page.evaluate_script('window.confirm = function() { return false; }')
end
```

Then you can proceed to rewrite your Capybara steps, so that first you make sure you stub the confirm box, and *then* you click on the link that triggers the confirm box:

```
When I ensure the confirm box returns OK
And I click on Remove
Then ...
```