# Capybara & Rspec: How to delete an account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm using Devise and writing a test for the scenario of a user deleting their own account but I'm stuck on how I would call up the confirm box and click OK.

Here is the link and my test:

```
<p><%= link_to "Delete my account", registration_path(resource_name), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete %></p>
```

spec/requests/users_spec.rb

```
scenario 'user deletes account' do
   make_user_and_login
   click_link('Account Settings')
   page.should have_selector('title', :text => 'Account Settings')
   click_link('Delete my account')
   # Are You Sure?
   # click OK in confirm box
   # page.should etc.....
end
```

How would this be done?

Comment: Hope this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458632/how-to-test-a-confirm-dialog-with-cucumber

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure capybara is using a driver which supports javascript.
Then try this:

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
```

Alternately, to cancel:

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.dismiss
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get: `Failure/Error: page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method 'switch_to' for #<Capybara::RackTest::Browser:0x588d0f8>`

Comment: You're using `Capybara::RackTest`, this is a headless browser without javascript support.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
page.evaluate_script('window.confirm = function() { return true; }')
```

this should work, then check for something like

```
page.should have_content "Account deleted"
```

Comment: I get this error when trying this: `Failure/Error: page.evaluate_script('window.confirm = function() { return true; }')
     Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError:
       Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError`

Comment: I got this too some time ago, not shure what caused it. For me it was solved by updating my gems

Comment: It is because you are using `Capybara::RackTest`. This driver does not support execution of any javascript

Answer (score 1):

As @suweller said, we all were using the `Capybara::RackTest` default driver.  However, without changing any settings and adding `:js => true` in my rspec tests I got them to pass, when before I got the same error as you were getting.

This allows me to then use `page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept` at least.