# How to test post request and follow redirects with capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, rake, capybara

I'm trying to test a post request with capybara and cucumber. I can't visit a page and press a link to send the request because it has a confirm dialogue and I haven't made it work with javascript so I'm trying to use the post method and then test if it redirects to the appropriated url but I'm getting:

```
No response yet. Request a page first. (Rack::Test::Error)
```

My code is:

```
page.driver.post url
page.driver.status_code.should be 302
follow_redirect!
```

It's working fine until `follow_redirect!`. I've tried `page.driver.follow_redirects!` but it doesn't work either.

Any help?

Comment: Which webdriver are you using?

Comment: I'm using default driver: rack_test

Answer (score 7):

```
Capybara::Rails::TestCase.class_eval do
  def post(url)
    page.driver.post url
    visit page.driver.response.location
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to dismiss the confirm dialogue by using this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2609244/560123

That way you wouldn't care about making the post by yourself, and instead trust your application code to do the post request.

Regards