# Testing for javascript alerts with Capybara webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara-webkit

i am using capybara , selenium ,webkit,and cucumber. 
How I can dismiss the popup in headless browser? It always by default accept "ok". My test case works great selenium(I use this code `page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.dismiss`) but fails for headless browser.

This is my test case

```
Feature: Deleting keywords
  In order to use the app
  I need to be able to delete keywords

  Background:
    Given the database contains no test data
    Given there are accounts and users
    And I am on the homepage
    And I am signed in as "user"

  Scenario:  Successfully deliting keyword 
    When I create the following keywords:
      | keyword   | descrip   | title    |
      | kitty  | hello  | Fluffy   | 

    Then I should see "Keyword created."
    When I follow "Keywords"
    Then I should see "kitty"
    When I attempt to delete the keyword "kitty"
    And I dismiss popup 
    Then there should be 1 keyword
    Then I should see "kitty"
```

Thanks for help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test a confirm dialog with Cucumber?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458632/how-to-test-a-confirm-dialog-with-cucumber)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it. I have to move dismiss popup step before delete so something like `When I attempt to delete the keyword "kw1" from the index-keywords page and dismiss the popup` and my step definition is now

```
When(/^I attempt to delete the keyword "(.*?)" from the index\-keywords page and dismiss the popup$/) do |keyword|
  page.driver.dismiss_js_confirms!
  delete_keyword_from_keywords_index_page(keyword)
end
```