# I'm trying to login to Facebook. After a successful login, I get a browser popup:

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumber, webdriver-io-v4

I'm trying to login to facebook, after successful login;  am getting one notification popup asking for allowing and block. I'm fine with either case. I am using webstorm IDE cucumber.

I have already tried `browser.alertDismiss()`, `browser.alertAccept()` none of them are working:
[image: alert]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5002648/10588784):

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
```

or

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.dismiss
```

That's ruby, but if you're using Selenium, I'm sure there's a javascript equivalent.

Comment: Hi Nathaniel, 
thank you for your response.
but its not working or  may be i am not fully aware that how it works.

let me explain you what and how i am trying , i am pretty new to this actually.


so i am using cucumber where in the feature file i am having my scenario as login to facebook as step below:
Given I am on the facebook page
When Enter valid username and password "<user>" "<password>" into the text box
Then I should login to my facebook account page

Comment: And this is my code:
etMyAccount (){

        browser.pause(3000);
        this.accountMessage.waitForVisible(2000);
        return this.accountMessage.isVisible();
    }

get accountMessage () { return browser.element('//*[@title="Facebook"]'); }

but in between i am not able to handle the notification.